# Cordova Run Error - Proxy?

Tags: android, cordova, proxy

I'm on Windows 7, I set all my proxies. As you can see it fails with error code 8, but anything I search for seems not to match my problem exactly.

When I try to build and run my app in cordova, I get this error. I have no idea what to do! Any advice? Thanks everyone!

```
C:\Users\310202751\Documents\CordovaProjects\Locator>cordova run
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\310202751\Documents\CordovaProjects\Locato
r\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device '84deb82e'.
Running: C:\Users\310202751\Documents\CordovaProjects\Locator\platforms\android\
gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\310202751\Documents\CordovaProjects\Locator\pl
atforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException
: Connection refused: connect
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketI
mpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja
va:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket
Impl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:1168)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConn
ection.java:1104)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo
nnection.java:1512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1440)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I actually ended up working around this problem because I couldn't solve it. I can create the project using Cordova and start it up with the libraries I want using the Command Prompt, and after I have it all set up I switched to Android Studio [or Eclipse] and ran it from there. Honestly it's better that way anyway because you have an IDE to use and a lot of the problems are solved for you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info!